Написание своего компоновщика, препроцессора, ассемблера
Я знаю что можно написать свой компилятор и поэтому есть хорошие книги, но можно ли написать свой препроцессор(подобный препроцессору в языке С/С++), ассемблер(т.е компилятор для языка ассемблера) и компоновщик? Может даже есть возможность написать свой загрузчик программ? Пожалуйста поделитесь любой информацией об этом.
Заранее огромное спасибо за любую информацию

Ну как-то же все это было написано? значит, можно :) Начните с "Компиляторов" Ахо-Ульмана-Лам-Сети...

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++

Harry, я уже писал свой компилятор. Мне интересно как пишется всё остальное

Dev18, в том вопросе только книги по С++. А мне нужны книги по написанию ассемблера, компоновщика и препроцессора

"я уже писал свой компилятор" -  Эм, препроцессор выполняет первый шаг при компиляции. Во всяком случае, в С/C++

user7860670 я писал свой язык программирования и там не было команд препроцессора, т.е он просто не был мне нужен

Если вы писали компилятор, значит и препроцессор можете. Что делает компилятор? Принимает текст и выдаёт машинные команды. Что делает препроцессор? Принимает текст и выдаёт другой текст. Ну и в чём проблема его реализовать?

Ассемблер - аналогично. Придумайте свою мнемонику для набора команд. Далее преобразуйте её в машинный код.

Если написали компилятор, то в чем проблема с препроцессорм? Препроцессинг это всего лишь текстовые подстановки, т.е. по сути редактирование текстового файла с помощью директив, которые в нем же и расположены. Для написания компоновщика требуется всего-то понимать требования ABI и систему команд (т.е. знать какие части объектного кода подлежат модификации при связывании нескольких объектных модулей, настроенных обычно на нулевой адрес, в один загрузочный образ, настроенный на заданный адрес)

Что касается информации (об ассемблере (компиляторе), который делает объектный код и компоновщике (линкере), делающим исполнительный образ), то почитайте про ELF и поиграйтесь с objdump (главное помните -- если долго вглядываться в текст на незнакомом языке, то постепенно его смысл начинает доходить до тебя)

Alexander Petrov и apv спасибо

То есть как я понял написать свой загрузчик для программ нельзя написать ( не написав свою ОС)

@МатвейЖуковский, я бы не смотрел на свой загрузчик столь пессимистично. Скорее всего в ELF содержится таблица имен, подлежаших изменению при релокации. Тогда надо выделить память (например, malloc-ом), mprotect-ом присвоить страничкам нужные атрибуты, прочесть из elf-а нужные секции, прибавить адрес секций в памяти к ролоциремым ячейкам в соответствии с таблицей релокации, в маленьком преходнике на ассемблере занести нужные адреса в регистры, которые используются как базовые (как их найти это отдельный вопрос) и перейти на стартовый адрес. По идее должно заработать

Спасибо avp. Теперь можно создать загрузчик программ без создания ОС

Ответ дали в комментариях Alexandr Petrov и avp. Мне надо изучить PE, ELF и COFF. А также узнать про ABI.
